# Android: Why the layout changes when I delete the drawable-hdpi folder

Tags: android-layout, android-drawable

I am currently developing the layout for 320dp devices. I have layout-sw320dp which have the following code for displaying 6 ImageButtons.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="4dp" >

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/info_image_button_90_90"
            android:id="@+id/info_image_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/matri_image_button_90_90"
            android:id="@+id/event_imgae_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/events_image_button_90_90"
            android:id="@+id/image_button_10" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ann_image_button_90_90"
            android:id="@+id/image_button_11" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/events_image_button_90_90"
            android:id="@+id/image_button_20" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/events_image_button_90_90"
            android:id="@+id/image_button_21" />

    </GridLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer  -->
<ListView
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list_view"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have images (90x90) for the ImageButton in drawable-ldpi. Till now the layout looks like this

[image]

But when I add a folder drawable-hdpi which have the same images as in drawable-ldpi, the layout changes to this

[image]

Why the layout is changed? while having the same device (Nexus One) and same Images (90x90)

Comment: Nexus One uses the resources from `drawable-hdpi` by default.

Comment: but drawable-hdpi have the same images as in drawable-ldpi. Then what's the best practise to design for devices of different resolution.

Comment: No. It's not the same. The resolutions are different for each density. Scroll down on this page and you'll see the details: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

If you say you are developing for 320dpi, that should xhdpi.

From [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> A set of six generalized densities:
>
> ```
> ldpi (low) ~120dpi
> mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
> hdpi (high) ~240dpi
> xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
> xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
> xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
> ```

Basically the system tries to find the best match for your drawables. When you had them only in the ldpi folder, well, that was the only choice - took them and scaled up them by xhdpi/ldpi = 320/120. When you added the **same** images in the hdpi folder, that became the best match, but they were scaled up now only by xhdpi/hdpi = 320/240, hence the smaller size.

Generally, if you find a good size for your images and you want a consistent size across the different densities, you need to keep the ratio between them.

Traditionally, mdpi is considered the standard, with a ratio of 1:1, and the rest as follows:

```
ldpi =    1 : 0.75
mdpi =    1 : 1
hdpi =    1 : 1.5
xhdpi =   1 : 2
xxhdpi =  1 : 3
xxxhdpi = 1 : 4
```